# how to set references to nodes in this example

Tags: ruby, hashmap, graph-theory

when I try and setup my graph it creates a near infinite loop in which every node holds the relation of every other node. But I just want `nodes.film_actor_hash’ to have a node name and a reference to the node. how do I get just a reference and not the node itself?

I should add if you just copy and paste my code into irb or pry you’ll see what i mean.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :film_actor_hash

  def initialize(name)
    self.name = name
    self.film_actor_hash = {}
  end
end

require_relative 'nodes'
class Graph
  attr_accessor :actors
  attr_accessor :films
  def initialize
    @actors = []
    @films = []
  end
end

graph = Graph.new()

a= Node.new("a")
b= Node.new("b")
c= Node.new("c")
d= Node.new("d")
e= Node.new("e")
f= Node.new("f")
g= Node.new("g")
h= Node.new("h")
i= Node.new("i")
j= Node.new("j")
kevin_bacon= Node.new("kevin_bacon")
l= Node.new("l")
m= Node.new("m")
n= Node.new("n")
o= Node.new("o")
p= Node.new("p")
q= Node.new("q")
r= Node.new("r")
s= Node.new("s")

one = Node.new("one")
two = Node.new("two")
three = Node.new("three")
four = Node.new("four")
five = Node.new("five")
six = Node.new("six")
seven = Node.new("seven")
eight = Node.new("eight")
nine = Node.new("nine")
ten = Node.new("ten")
eleven = Node.new("eleven")
twelve = Node.new("twelve")
thirteen = Node.new("thirteen")
fourteen = Node.new("fourteen")
fifteen = Node.new("fifteen")
sixteen = Node.new("sixteen")
seventeen = Node.new("seventeen")
eighteen = Node.new("eighteen")
nineteen = Node.new("nineteen")

a.film_actor_hash['sixteen'] = sixteen
a.film_actor_hash['one'] = one
b.film_actor_hash['one'] = one
b.film_actor_hash['two'] = two
c.film_actor_hash['two'] = two
c.film_actor_hash['three'] = three
d.film_actor_hash['three'] = three
d.film_actor_hash['four'] = four
e.film_actor_hash['four'] = four
e.film_actor_hash['five'] = five
f.film_actor_hash['five'] = five
f.film_actor_hash['six'] = six
g.film_actor_hash['six'] = six
g.film_actor_hash['seven'] = seven
h.film_actor_hash['seven'] = seven
h.film_actor_hash['eight'] = eight
i.film_actor_hash['eight'] = eight
i.film_actor_hash['nine'] = nine
j.film_actor_hash['nine'] = nine
j.film_actor_hash['ten'] = ten
l.film_actor_hash['ten'] = ten
l.film_actor_hash['eleven'] = eleven
m.film_actor_hash['eleven'] = eleven
m.film_actor_hash['twelve'] = twelve
n.film_actor_hash['twelve'] = twelve
n.film_actor_hash['thirteen'] = thirteen
o.film_actor_hash['thirteen'] = thirteen
o.film_actor_hash['fourteen'] = fourteen
p.film_actor_hash['fourteen'] = fourteen
p.film_actor_hash['fifteen'] = fifteen
kevin_bacon.film_actor_hash['fifteen'] = fifteen
kevin_bacon.film_actor_hash['sixteen'] = sixteen

one.film_actor_hash['kevin_bacon'] = kevin_bacon
one.film_actor_hash['a'] = a
two.film_actor_hash['a'] = a
two.film_actor_hash['b'] = b
three.film_actor_hash['b'] = b
three.film_actor_hash['c'] = c
four.film_actor_hash['c'] = c
four.film_actor_hash['d'] = d
five.film_actor_hash['d'] = d
five.film_actor_hash['e'] = e
six.film_actor_hash['e'] = e
six.film_actor_hash['f'] = f
seven.film_actor_hash['f'] = f
seven.film_actor_hash['g'] = g
eight.film_actor_hash['g'] = g
eight.film_actor_hash['h'] = h
nine.film_actor_hash['h'] = h
nine.film_actor_hash['i'] = i
ten.film_actor_hash['i'] = i
ten.film_actor_hash['j'] = j
eleven.film_actor_hash['j'] = j
eleven.film_actor_hash['l'] = l
twelve.film_actor_hash['l'] = l
twelve.film_actor_hash['m'] = m
thirteen.film_actor_hash['m'] = m
thirteen.film_actor_hash['n'] = n
fourteen.film_actor_hash['n'] = n
fourteen.film_actor_hash['o'] = o
fifteen.film_actor_hash['o'] = o
fifteen.film_actor_hash['p'] = p
sixteen.film_actor_hash['p'] = p
sixteen.film_actor_hash['kevin_bacon'] = kevin_bacon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually working correctly. In Ruby, "the node itself" *is* its reference. There's no way to access the underlying object directly, so your code is just passing around pointers.

The problem is here:

> I should add if you just copy and paste my code into irb or pry you’ll see what i mean.

When you evaluate an expression in irb/pry, Ruby calls `inspect` on the result and prints it to console. The problem is that `inspect` is recursive i.e. when you inspect a custom class or hash, it also `inspect`s the contents of the class/hash. Since all of your objects reference each other through their instance variables, you end up in an infinite recursive loop. I'm guessing `inspect` eventually hits a stack limit and gives up.

Observe the difference:

```
sixteen.film_actor_hash.size # 2 elements in the hash
sixteen.film_actor_hash.inspect.size # 18743520 characters in its string representation!
```

Technically there's nothing you need to fix as long you don't need to `inspect` your objects. But for sanity you can just redefine `inspect` to not be recursive:

```
class Node
  def inspect
    "#<#{self.class}:0x%x #{self.name}>" % object_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you've saved me from another headache. I was told that ruby code doesn't work the way I wanted and that i should go back and rethink my design. but this little modification you offered makes everything run smoothly. 

if you have some time could you elaborate on this part and how `#<#{self.class}:0x%x #{self.name}>" % object_id` changes inspect's recursive nature?

Comment: mainly the `:0x%x ` confuses me. 

also i tried `"string: % object_id` and it just returned string; this too confuses me.

Comment: @WolfgangTruong `"%x" % y` formats y as a hexadecimal string. I chose this format arbitrarily because it kinda matches up with the default  `inspect` implementation. But you can define the string any way you want as long as it doesn't end up `inspect`ing `self.film_actor_hash`